# Why Flutter return diifferent time between Device and DateTime/TimeOfDay

Tags: dart, flutter

Hope anyone can help.

I try to get current time using `DateTime/TimeOfDay`, but I get wrong result.

I use `TimeOfDay.now()` to get current time.

Here the result look like:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Here is the full code:

```
TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay.now();

@override
void initState() {
  _timeController =
        new TextEditingController(text: '${_time.hour}:${_time.minute}');
}
```

Comment: does it always happen? put your code

Comment: Yes, for Android only. I was edited my question above (adding my code).

Comment: it's working fine in my simulator

Comment: restart your emulator,  also put the code of your textfield widget

Comment: Looks like not taking timezone into account.

Comment: @diegoveloper Yes, it's working fine on Simulator. But the problem is on Android Emulator.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I don't know was happened.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just try to install it on real device and it's working fine. Maybe the problem is at my emulator.

Comment: Did you suspend your computer while keeping the emulator running? This causes such issues for me on OSX with Android emulator.

Comment: No, I don't. Until now I don't know what the actually causes.